# Shouldn't the imports be absolute by default in python27?

Tags: python, import

Imagine the directory structure:

```
/
    a/
        __init__.py
        b.py
        c.py
    c.py
```

File `/a/b.py` looks like:

```
import c
should_be_absolute = c
```

All the other files (including `__init__`) are empty.

When running a test script (using python 2.7):

```
import a.b
print a.b.should_be_absolute
```

with `PYTHONPATH=/` from an empty directory (so nothing is added to `PYTHONPATH` from current directory) I get

```
<module 'a.c' from '/a/c.py'>
```

where according to [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) and the statement `import <> is always absolute` I would expect:

```
<module 'c' from '/c.py'>
```

The output is as expected when I remove the `/a/c.py` file.

What am I missing? And if this is the correct behavior - how to import the `c` module from `b` (instead of `a.c`)?

**Update:**

According to [python dev mailing list](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/status-of-absolute-import-w-python-2-7-td1850742.html) it appears to be a bug in the documentation. The imports are **not** absolute by default in python27.

Comment: What is your complete pythonpath? Is it only / ?  You should probably be using a root package name

Comment: FWIW, this works as you expect in Python 3.

Comment: @jdi - yes the root is the only thing in the PYTHONPATH (edited the original post to make it more explicit)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you need to add `from __future__ import absolute_import` or use `importlib.import_module('c')` on Python 2.7

It is default on Python 3.

There was a bug in Python: [`__future__.py` and its documentation claim absolute imports became mandatory in 2.7, but they didn't](http://bugs.python.org/issue14494).

Comment: You are right! After further digging I found the link to the [python-dev mailing list](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/status-of-absolute-import-w-python-2-7-td1850742.html) confirming that the absolute_import feature is not on by default in python27.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only adding `/` to your PYTHONPATH, then the search order could still be looking for `c` in the current directory. It would be a lot better if you placed everything under a root package, and referred to it absolutely:

```
/myPackage
    a/
        __init__.py
        b.py
        c.py
    __init__.py
    c.py
```

And a PYTHONPATH like:  `export PYTHONPATH=/:$PYTHONPATH`

So in your `a.c` you would do and of these:

```
from myPackage import c
from myPackage.c import Foo
import myPackage.c
```

This way, it is always relative to your package.

Comment: Thanks but the question is more is this a correct behavior rather than how to reorganize the code to make it work. The actual problem that I am solving is that the 'c' is the name of the python build-in module and the code in the package that I am working is shadowing it (and according to the python docs should not)

Answer (score -1):

"Absolute" doesn't mean the one that you think it does; instead, it means that the "usual" package resolving procedure takes place: first, it looks in the directory of the package, then in all the elements of sys.path; which includes the elements from PYTHONPATH.

If you *really* want to, you can use tools like the imp module, but I'd recommend against it for something like this.  Because in general, you shouldn't ever have to create a module with the same name as one in the standard Python distribution.

Comment: Thanks @Ivo but the [PEP 328#rationale-for-absolute-imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports) states that the absolute import _will always be a module or package reachable from sys.path_. There is nothing about the lookup in the package directory first. Can you point to some resource that documents the behavior that your described please?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import is very clear on the process as it is implemented: "If the module being imported is supposed to be contained within a package then the second argument passed to find_module(), __path__ on the parent package, is used as the source of paths."

Comment: "first, it looks in the directory of the package".  Nope, that's relative import.