# Why can't absolute imports find my module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-style

I have a Python 2.7 project that looks like this:

> myproject\
>
> ```
> - __init__.py
> - __main__.py
> - foo.py
> ```

I'd like to use [absolute imports](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159503/whats-wrong-with-relative-imports-in-python), as required by PEP 8, but when I try to do this in `__main__`.py:

```
from myproject.foo import bar
```

With `python -m myproject`

I get:

> ImportError: No module named myproject.foo

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you do to specifically cause that exception? `python -m myproject`? If so please edit your question with that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more Googling it [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726633/shouldnt-the-imports-be-absolute-by-default-in-python27), all I needed to do was add:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

This adds some future-proofing for Python 3.Note that PyDev cannot find the modules this way. I'll open a separate question for that.

Comment: Might want to mention in your question that you're using Python 2.x (and tag it as such, too, for relevance)

Answer (score 1):

For that to work, `myproject` has to be on your Python path. You can do that externally by setting the `PYTHONPATH` variable, or inside the program by adding it to `sys.path`.

(Note that there's no convention to use double-underscore names on anything other than `__init__.py`. Your `__main__.py` seems a very odd name.)

Comment: `__main__`is understood by pythonwhen you `python -m` a package.

Comment: I used `__main__.py` because Python [looks for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py) when `python myproject` in run.

Comment: Cool, for some reason I'd never come across that before.

Comment: `__main__.py` also allows you to zip up your project to `myproject.zip` (or whatever) and run `python myproject`, @DanielRoseman